# Swagger - Schema no muestra el default de un campo de clase

Tags: swagger

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un server web Apis (.Net6) que utiliza Swagger/Swashbuckle.

En el siguiente ejemplo, muestro una clase con un campo que tiene valor default "BU".

El problema que tengo y necesito resolver, es que el schema de la interface
gráfica Swagger NO muestra el valor default de los campos, en este caso "BU".

public class AfectacionBienesDeUso
{

```
   [RegularExpression("BU|DU")]        
   public string Campo { get; set; } = "BU";

}
```

end class

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el atributo `DefaultValue`

```
[RegularExpression("BU|DU")]
[DefaultValue("BU")]
public string Campo { get; set; } = "BU";
```